# Erro ao executar selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Amigo, boa noite!

Estou começando minhas caminhadas em programação, e sempre venho aqui tirar algumas dúvidas, porém hoje realizei meu cadastro aqui para pedi ajuda de vocês.
Esses dias eu participei de um curso de imersão para criação de um chatbot para whatsapp.. porém quando abro o prompt de comando para executar o arquivo, recebo está informação:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Revisando o meu código, não encontrei erro de escrita (acredito que não).
Abaixo segue parte do meu código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me ajudar a entender este erro?
Seria algum pacote que não importei corretamente?

Abraços,

Comment: Por favor, coloque o código e não imagem. Veja as instruções:https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: esta certo que o selenium esta instalado?

Comment: @Hartnäcking veja se lhe ajuda com os comentários: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/707/coment%c3%a1rios-enlatados-para-situa%c3%a7%c3%b5es-comuns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mensagem de erro `ModuleNotFoundError` indica que o pacote não está instalado no seu ambiente. Com base nos prints que você enviou, presumo que está utilizando o Anaconda (note que há um `(base)` no seu prompt), assim sendo, utilize o comando abaixo para instalar o Selenium:

```
conda install -c conda-forge selenium
```

Comment: Olá Rafael, conseguir resolver o meu problema! De fato, eu não tinha realizado a instalação do pacote :)
Agora ele roda.. Como mencionei, estou estudando python e sempre estou caindo nestas pegadinhas!!!
Abraços.. ;)

Comment: @Amaro_Junior_1982, Se essa resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 

Comment: Obrigado Icaro...

Ainda estou aprendendo a utilizar a plataforma.

Comment: Olá @Amaro_Junior_1982, bem vindo à comunidade Python ! Bons estudos !